# Elasticsearch.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install

Tags: elasticsearch, service, elastic-stack, systemd

what is this Error ??::

root@pc:~# **sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service**
or

## root@pc:~# **sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch**

---

elasticsearch.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install. Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable elasticsearch

---

im install elastic this refrence:
http://robwillis.info/2017/04/elk-5-on-ubuntu-pt-2-installing-and-configuring-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-nginx/

thanks my helping and fix my problem

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and couldn't start my elasticsearch on Ubuntu 16.04. Found the solution [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/9) (fcoelho's answer). What needs to be done is to set `START_DAEMON=true` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch`. It is commented out by default.